# Python MySQL exception Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
 def add(self):
        myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root",passwd = "110277", database = "ims")
        cur=myconn.cursor()
        try:
            if self.var_emp_id.get()=='':
                messagebox.showerror('Error','Employee ID Must be required',parent=self.root)
            else:
                cur.execute('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid=?',(self.var_emp_id.get(),))
                row=cur.fetchone()
                if  row!=None:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error","This Employee ID already assigned, try different",parent=self.root )
                else:
                    add_user= ('INSERT INTO employee (eid,name,email,gender,contact,dob,doj,pass,utype,address,salary) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(     
                                
                                self.var_emp_id.get(),
                                self.var_name.get(),
                                self.var_email.get(),
                                self.var_gender.get(),
                                self.var_contact.get(),
                                self.var_dob.get(),
                                self.var_doj.get(),
                                self.var_pass.get(),
                                self.var_utype.get(),
                                self.txt_address.get('1.0',END),
                                self.var_salary.get(),
                    ))
                             
                    myconn.commit()
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success","Employee Add Successfully",parent=self.root) 
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due  to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)
```

Error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: It looks like this line has a extra comma, the number of expected parameter is only one. `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid=?',(self.var_emp_id.get(),))`

Comment: @ArpitChinmay, the extra comma makes it a tuple, it's needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your password argument is named incorrectly

This:

```
myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root",passwd = "110277", database = "ims")
```

Should be:

```
myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root",password = "110277", database = "ims")
```